# Inserting a comma in between columns in text tile

Tags: python

The problem is I have this text, csv file which is missing commas and I would like to insert it in order to run the file on LaTex and make a table.  I have a MWE of a code from another problem which I ran and it did not work.  Is it possible someone could guide me on how to change it.

I have used a Python code which provides a blank file, and another one which provides a blank document, and another which removes the spaces.

```
 import fileinput
 input_file = 'C:/Users/Light_Wisdom/Documents/Python Notes/test.txt'
 output= open('out.txt','w+')
 with open('out.txt', 'w+') as output:
     for each_line in fileinput.input(input_file):
    output.write("\n".join(x.strip() for x in each_line.split(',')))
```

text file contains more numbers but its like this

```
0   2.58612
0.00616025  2.20018
0.0123205   1.56186
0.0184807   0.371172
0.024641    0.327379
0.0308012   0.368863
0.0369615   0.322228
0.0431217   0.171899
Outcome
0.049282,   -0.0635003
0.0554422,  -0.110747
0.0616025,  0.0701394
0.0677627,  0.202381
0.073923,   0.241264
0.0800832,  0.193697
```

Renewed Attempt:

```
with open("CSV.txt","r") as file:
    new = list(map(lambda x: ''.join(x.split()[0:1]+[","]+x.split()[0:2]),file.readlines()))
with open("New_CSV.txt","w+") as output:
    for i in new:
        output.writelines(i)
        output.writelines("\n")
```

Comment: Do you need to see the text file?

Comment: That'd be helpful. The entire file isn't necessary but the layout would be helpful

Comment: @DSC It looks like that I can manually do the header because its getting inserted into Latex its the numbers that bum me out.

Comment: Can you also give the expected outcome? Do you just need to place commas between the numbers in a row or also between the different rows?

Comment: @DSC I added the outcome in the code block

Comment: Read in the file "normally", and write it out as a `csv` file.  Both of these techniques are readily available with an on-line search.  Use the `csv` module to make the second part easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be using `.split` and `.join` by splitting the line into a list and then joining the list separated by commas. This enables us to handle several subsequent spaces in the file:

```
f1 = open(input_file, "r")

with open("out.txt", 'w') as f2:
    for line in f1:
        f2.write(",".join(line.split()) + "\n")

f1.close()
```

You can also use `csv` to handle the writing automatically:

```
import csv

f1 = open(input_file, "r")

with open("out.txt", 'w') as f2:
    writer = csv.writer(f2)
    for line in f1:
        writer.writerow(line.split())

f1.close()
```